# Why is a 32 character hex string not a md5 hash?

Tags: hash

This string, when dropped into hash detection tools, is not being identified as a hash. As far as I knew, an md5 has was a 32 digit string with hex numbers. Everything below is hex. So what other rules does md5 have that prevent this from being a hash?

8019ed9fa0c5d1c36c7ef3a4e931205368da339079331

Here is just one example of an ID failure for this string:

https://www.onlinehashcrack.com/hash-identification.php#results

"Your hash may be one of the following :
Sorry we cannot identify your hash.."

Comment: @bashCypher I think you misunderstand me. I don't think you are dumb for this, I think this is an easy mistake to make and I think there is value in leaving it up for future googlers who will make the same mistake (especially if they don't realize that md5 needs to be 32 chars). TL;DR I'm asking you to put your pride aside and let others benefit from your question :)

Comment: @MikeOunsworth I do not agree. There is nothing to learn from a typo that a 10 year old doesn't  know. Please do not edit this post again.

Comment: @bashCypher - please stop being rude to people who are trying to help you. Also, no, we will not delete, as that would remove rep from the answerer.

Answer (score 4):

It's not 32 digits. It's 45. That's 180 bits, not the 128 bits you expect from md5.

You can see this easily in a monospace font:

```
8019ed9fa0c5d1c36c7ef3a4e931205368da339079331
d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e
```

(The lower hash is the md5sum of an empty string)

Apart from that it's important to realise that a hex number is just another number. Most hashes doesn't carry any metadata in the hash identifying the algorithm or what kind of number it is.